# nesting python generators (one inside another)

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have two functions (generator).

```
def a():
  yield 1
  yield 2


def b():
  yield 'A'
  yield 'B'
  yield a()
```

Now I want to iterate over `b()` and expect it should output `A B 1 2`. But no. Its giving this.

```
In [11]: for i in b():
   ....:     print i
   ....:     
A
B
<generator object a at 0x10fc3ddc0>
```

How can I get the required output?

Comment: Why would you expect `A B 1 2`? You're `yield`ing the *generator object itself*, not its contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On python3.3+, you can use [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380):

```
def b():
    yield 'A'
    yield 'B'
    yield from a()
```

In versions prior to python3.3, you need to yield the values explicitly in a loop:

```
def b():
    yield 'A'
    yield 'B'
    for item in a():
        yield item
```

Comment: My bad luck its not available on python2. But this is what I expected actually!

Comment: @ReutSharabani -- Sorry, it means I was having a hard time typing :-)  You should still be able to see my comment on your now deleted post, but basically I was pushing back on the notion that `yield from` is simply "syntatic sugar" as it is true generator delegation -- and accomplishing the same thing prior to `yield from` is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3. You could use `yield from`

```
def a():
  yield 1
  yield 2


def b():
  yield 'A'
  yield 'B'
  yield from a()
```